# Denied access when using Spring Security RoleHierarchy

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, roles

I'm configuring the role access to my REST WSs in my web application and I would like to implement a role Hierarchy.
I defined this bean

```
@Bean
public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(
        UserManagement.RoleEnum.ADMIN.getRoleString() + " > " + UserManagement.RoleEnum.WEBUI.getRoleString()
    );


    return roleHierarchy;
}

private SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> webExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    return defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
}
```

Then in my `SecurityConfiguration.configure(HttpSecurity http)` method I write:

```
String[] URLsToBeProtectedAsWebUi = {PREFIX + "/auth/tokens/**"}; 

http
    .csrf().disable()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationExceptionEntryPoint())
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .expressionHandler(webExpressionHandler())
        .antMatcher(PREFIX + "/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(URLsToBeProtectedAsWebUi).hasRole(UserManagement.RoleEnum.WEBUI.getRoleString())
    .and()
    .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenProcessingFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

The problem is that if I call the `PREFIX + "/auth/tokens/**` WS by using a token for the WEB UI user everything works fine, but if I use a token for the ADMIN user then I get a `403 access denied` response, but I expect the ADMIN should be allowed to consume the service because he is higher in the role hierarchy.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The error was in the DB: the roles were wrongly arranged to the users